# Is a print method considered standard in an SDK, or only a toString?

Tags: java, printing, sdk

I am putting together a Java SDK. I have created a few different classes, and have creating toString() methods for each class. But I am finding that when I am using my own SDK, instead of wrapping my object in a SysOut, it looks cleaner to just do the following, and create print() methods along with my toString() methods.

```
Object object = new Object(); 
object.print();
```

Is it standard to include print() methods for Java classes? Or should I be sticking with SysOut(Object.toString()).

```
Object object = new Object(); 
System.out.println(object.toString());
```

Edit: As a bonus, since we are in the realm of "better" practice to begin with... Is it more common(to try and make this more than an opinion...), to show the toString, or go with the implied toString call?

```
Object object = new Object(); 
System.out.println(object.toString());
```

or

```
Object object = new Object(); 
System.out.println(object);
```

Comment: I've never come across .print() technique you describe in 15 years of Java... Sounds like ruby's .inspect mechanism...

Comment: _Is it standard to include `print()` methods for Java classes?_ No. Keep serialization logic separate from your object's behavior.

Comment: If you want to create an example why its best to keep serialization logic separate I'd accept as answer

Comment: Why should you spend time to implement what is basically a one-liner (It's actually `System.out.println(object)`) when for all you know the user will want to print it somewhere else, like `System.err`, some other `PrintWriter`, maybe print several together, or whatever? Why bother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No, it is not "standard", you should leave to the developer where to (and if) print, give them just the String representation of your classes.

2)

> ```
> Object object = new Object(); 
> System.out.println(object.toString());
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> Object object = new Object(); 
> System.out.println(object);
> ```

It's the same, since System.out.println(Object o) calls String.valueOf(o) that calls o.toString(). If you are sure that object is not null use `System.out.println(object.toString());` otherwise use `System.out.println(object);`.